# Limit the associatedtype to someClass

Tags: swift, associated-types

how can I limit my associatedtype to `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`?

[image]

Comment: Show code, not pictures of code, and _explain_ the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can constraint associatedtype quite easily:

```
public protocol MJRfreshAble {
    associatedtype RefreshableViewType where RefreshableViewType: UIScrollView

    var refreshableView: RefreshableViewType { get }
}

class TestVC1: UIViewController, MJRfreshAble {
    typealias RefreshableViewType = UITableView

    let tableView = UITableView()

    var refreshableView: RefreshableViewType {
        return tableView
    }
}

class TestVC2: UIViewController, MJRfreshAble {
    typealias RefreshableViewType = UICollectionView

    let collectionView = UICollectionView()

    var refreshableView: RefreshableViewType {
        return collectionView
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not so familiar with the associatedtype in protocal，thank a lot